# Javascript shortened if statement add else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shortcut

I'm using a pre-compiled code and I have to put an `else` statement for the following if statement:

```
if(F && F[0]) for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) readImage( F[i], '1417', '1417');
```

I usually work with this type of statement shortcut:

```
if(dog == 'billy') ? true : false ;
```

But can't figure out that first one.

Comment: That's not a "shortened" `if` statement, it's just an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a single line of code in `if`/`for`/`while` etc. statements without using brackets. The following code would not execute `bar()`, but would execute `rab()`:

```
var foo = false;
if (foo) 
    bar();
rab();
```

Indented your code would look like this:

```
if(F && F[0]) 
    for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) 
        readImage( F[i], '1417', '1417');
```

Which is essentially the same as this:

```
if(F && F[0]) {
    for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) {
        readImage( F[i], '1417', '1417');
    }
}
```

So you can just rewrite it to:

```
if(F && F[0]) {
    for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) {
        readImage( F[i], '1417', '1417');
    }
} else {
    //Something else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mashing things into a single line often adds confussion. Your first block of code is this:

```
if(F && F[0]) 
    for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) 
        readImage( F[i], '1417', '1417');
```

So all you need to do is add the else:

```
if(F && F[0]) 
    for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) 
        readImage( F[i], '1417', '1417');
else
   //something
```

I personally find it a lot easier to use the brackets, it makes everything much more understandable:

```
if(F && F[0]) {
    for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) {
        readImage( F[i], '1417', '1417');
    }
}
else {
   //something
}
```

---

In regards to your usual statement, you are confusing two different techniques, the standard if:

```
if(dog == 'billy') 
    //true 
else 
    //false
```

and the conditional operator (often called ternary), which does not require the `if` part, and is commonly use for conditional assignment:

```
var isTheDogCalledBilly = dog == 'billy' ? true : false;
```

Comment: You forget easier to maintain.

Comment: Would JS be smart enough to know that the `else` belonged to the `if` and not the `for`? **Edit**: Apparently so. `if (false) for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(i); else console.log('foo');` outputs `foo` but looks horribly confusing.

Comment: And then of course it gets really fun once you start nesting `if`s: `if (number < 10) if (number <= 5) console.log('lt5'); else console.log('gt5'); else console.log('gte10')`